# jQuery $(html, props) (DOM creation) ignores props map

Tags: jquery

I'm unable to correctly create DOM elements using jQuery (1.3.2):

```
var ev_t;
$("#add-event").click(function() {
    ev_t = $("<form>", { action : "someURL" }).hide().appendTo(document.body);
    var fields = $("<div>").appendTo(ev_t);
    fields.load("someURL", function() {
        $("<input>", { type: "submit", value: "Add" }).appendTo(ev_t);
        ev_t.dialog();
    });
    ev_t.submit(function() {
        // form submission ...
        return false;
    });
    return false;
});
```

The  and  elements are inserted but **none of the attributes** (form action and input type and value) **are set**. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second argument to jQuery (1.3+), when there is one, is the context for the the selector, not a set of attributes to apply.  Try:

```
ev_t = $('<form>').attr('action','someUrl").hide().appendTo(document.body);
```

and

```
$("<input>").attr({ type: "submit", value: "Add" }).appendTo(ev_t);
```

Or upgrade to jQuery 1.4+

Comment: I solved by upgrading to 1.4.1 but I'm going to accept this answer as it explains how to do that in 1.3.*. It can be useful to people who are unable to upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

**It seems this functionality is only available from [jQuery 1.4](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/):**

> As of jQuery 1.4, we can pass a map of
>   properties to the second argument.
>   This argument accepts a superset of
>   properties that can be passed to the
>   .attr() method. Furthermore, any event
>   type can be passed in, and the
>   following jQuery methods can be
>   called: val, css, html, text, data,
>   width, height, or offset.

Upgrade your jQuery libraries and you should be fine.

Comment: I had a couple of jQuery UI 1.7 things break with 1.4.  You might want to upgrade jQuery UI to 1.8 at the same time or wait until they both stabilize.

Comment: I missed that line while reading the documentation (what an idiot). Upgraded to 1.4 and ui 1.8: now it works. Thanks